# ReplaceAll does not function Apex

Tags: apex, datetime, string, replace

Hello everybody I am managing data from a LWC form where the user inputs some data and I pass it to validate into an apex class. This validation manages the format of a date time value: I want the next format '13:14:18' and the input datetime field is the next one '10:40:56.000Z'.
So I have a datetime validation which is the next one:

```
public static Boolean validTime(String input){
    System.debug('en validTime...'+ input);
    Boolean valid = true;
    if((input.contains('.000Z'))){
        input.replaceAll('.000Z','');
        input.left(8);
    }
    
}
```

the problem is inside of the first if condition... because the input.replaceAll('.000Z','') is not working and also the input.left(8). In my debug does not change anything:
[image]

could anybody tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable. This means that all String functions return a new String value rather than modifying the String you called the method on, since a String cannot change. You need to capture those changes in a variable.

```
input = input.replace('.000Z','');
```

Note that `replaceAll` expects a "regular expression", which isn't what you necessarily need here. Just use `replace`, instead, or you can even just use `removeEnd`.

```
input = input.removeEnd('.000Z');
```